# How to create alpine package without git?

Tags: alpine-linux, apk-tools

If I already have all the files how do I package them up into an .apk file that I can later installed?

Sort of an equivalent of `fakeroot dpkg-deb -b package-dir package.deb`, or something to achieve similar functionality, without having to go through the mess of a fake repository or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you already have alpine with `alpine-sdk` or `build-base` and `abuild` installed, you need to know that APK signs digitally the APK. 
So first you need to create the keys with:

```
$ abuild-keygen -a
```

Then, if you have the APKBUILD file in /tmp:

```
$ cd /tmp && abuild -r
```

You'll find the built apk according to what is written in `/etc/abuild/abuild.conf`, that by default is set to:

```
REPODEST=$HOME/packages/
```

In order to install the APK (since as I said is digitally signed), you should copy the public key produced by abuild-keygen in `/etc/apk/keys` or alternatively add the argument `--allow-untrusted` to `apk add $package`.

.: Francesco